# GStreamer jpegenc factory error: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80

Tags: cross-platform, gstreamer, ld, libjpeg, raspberry-pi2

I'm developing an application from my PC (Ubuntu 14.04) to Raspberry pi 2. I'm trying to use GStreamer-1.0  because it has hardware acceleration support for Raspberry Pi. Shortly brief about application; getting frames from an IP camera and save them with 1 FPS to somewhere on the file system. I can save images from command line with;

```
gst-launcg-1.0 rtspsrc location="" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=1/ ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=/somewhere/to/save/images/and/save/type
```

but I want to do this with C++ code and I'll use these images to do some processings. I've installed gstreamer, gst-plugins-base, gst-plugins-good, gst-plugins-ugly, gst-plugins-bad, gst-libav, gst-omx to Raspberry Pi and Installed gstreamer (and requirements, zlib, glib and libffi) to Ubuntu for cross development. I want to create a pipeline for this process but when I want to create `"jpegenc"` element it is giving me error which is not about gstreamer;

```
Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80
```

But I didn't understand anything because my apps ldd output has no dependency about libjpeg.so.62;

```
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.8 (0x74b51000)
```

I had have not libjpeg62 at both of my systems. But I've installed libjpeg62 (I wanted libjpeg62-dev but sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev wanted to remove some packages which are necessary to me then I decline it) and linked libjpeg.so with (RPi);

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.62 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so
```

But nothing changed. I've looked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25759/linking-issues-with-libjpeg) but I'm not compiling it from R-Pi and it didn't affect anything,

Comment: I've created a test.cpp file which is creating just `jpegenc` element from factory. It was created without any problem. Can I use, raspberry-pi libs with copy them to my ubuntu machine /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ or /cross/compiler/toolchain/lib?

Comment: I've tried to compile whole project from Raspberry Pi and it didn't give any error, it just created all factories what I've wanted. So this error about cross-compiling settings.

Comment: I'm using `'pngenc'` instead of `'jpegenc'`, problem has gone for now. But I'm still wondering about why jpeg libraries are confusing my mind and PC.

Answer (score 0):

uninstalled all the jpeg versions (both 62 and 80), and reinstalled jpeg8 by using

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8
```

Comment: I've already did it but nothing changed. I've also removed cross-compiled GStreamer library from Ubuntu and copied from Raspberry Pi it was still same. I think my ld or whatever looking /usr/lib/x86_64... for glib and jpeg because I compiled from Raspberry Pi it worked

Comment: But when I type `sudo apt-get remove libjpeg8`, package manager attempts to remove too many package. Package manager removed  631 packages which are 4.776 MB and install 1 package which is `libgpod4-nogtk`. Is this a problem?

Comment: It is a big problem. Ubuntu is not opening now. I am seeing purple Ubuntu loading screen for an hour.

Comment: I've reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 and checked `ldconfig -p | grep jpeg` output, it is `libopenjpeg.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjpeg.so.2` and `libjpeg.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8` but problem still same.